# Improve datatables display of data

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I'd like to know if there are solutions to improve the displaying time of data (10k rows), it currently takes 7~8 seconds. I've checked out [this post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38813/performance-improvements) but it does not really change anything to my current loading time.

Here's my code :

```
currentAuditTable = $('#auditTable').DataTable({
        responsive: false,
        ajax: {
            "url": restURI + 'orch/search/audit/'+encodeURI(auditFlowId)+'/'+encodeURI(auditEventId),
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "type": "GET",
            "data": null,
            "error": function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                if (globalVars.unloaded) {
                    return;
                }
                manageAjaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            }
        },
        order: [3, 'desc'],
        pageLength: 50,
        autoWidth: true,
        deferRender: true,
        columns: [
            {"data": "EVENT_ID", "defaultContent": "", "sClass": "text-center limitedWidth", "width": "5%"},
            {"data": "OPERATION_NAME", "defaultContent": "", "sClass": "text-center limitedWidth", "width": "10%"},
            {"data": "OPERATION_STATUS", "defaultContent": "", "sClass": "text-center limitedWidth", "width": "10%"},
            {"data": "CREATE_DATE", "defaultContent": "", "sClass": "text-center limitedWidth", "width": "10%"},
            {"data": "OPERATION_MESSAGE", "defaultContent": "", "sClass": "text-center limitedWidth", "width": "25%"},
            {"data": "OPERATION_DATA", "defaultContent": "", "sClass": "text-center limitedWidth", "width": "25%"}
        ]
    });
```

I would appreciate any help because I'm stuck right now. Thank you !

Comment: Can use server side processing which would only send data on as needed basis. Will introduce a bit of latency switching pages and filtering, searching etc though

Comment: Note we don't know how long the actual data request takes before the plugin even has the data. Inspect the actual ajax request in browser dev tools

Comment: It takes 2.92 s.

Comment: So that's almost 1/2 of the time right there

Comment: I may have to inspect the back request, but I wanted to know if there are any solutions on datatables plugin which help, like properties...

Comment: Another thing you could do is send smaller dataset to get it displayed...make another request yourself in background and add to table data yourself once the larger set arrives

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try it, thanks !